# Selecting same choice twice in a row doesn't work for dropdown select element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/r4zju/3/ - where I'm selecting the font for text in a contentEditable box. If you select the word "text" and then select comic from the drop down, the font changes as expected.  But if you then select the word "some" and decide to make it comic also, selecting comic from the drop down doesn't do it because "change" for the dropdown isn't triggered, since the selection is already comic. I tried doing a blur() after the first selection but that didn't help.

Does anyone know how I can go back and select comic again without selecting another font in between?

Thanks

```
$('select#fontname').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();       
        document.execCommand('fontName', false, selected);
        $(this).blur();
        $('#font').html(selected);
        $(this).blur();

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-set the selector after each change event.  Change your last line to:

```
 $(this).prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Not quite what you're after, but one step closer.

Comment: That's close enough!  Thanks a lot.